# Recorrer un array con un for each dentro de una promesa en Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, promesas, foreach

estoy aprendiendo a programar en JS y tengo que traer de una api un jason con información: https://assistanceservices.herokuapp.com/api/supporttrucks/
Tengo que dibujar los elementos en un mapa y estoy intentando hacerlo con promises. Si yo le paso un id hardcodeandolo, lo dibuja correctamente.
El problema es que yo tengo que dibujar todos los elementos, por eso lo que me pareció mas lógico es usar un for each. Pero dentro del for each, el array aparece como vacío a pesar de que lo llené antes.
Aclaro que el mapa está hecho con Leaflet.
Les comparto el código:

```
    var url = Config.url;
    var urlTrucks = '/supporttrucks/';
    var urlStates = '/truckstates/';
    var trucksIds = [];
    var promesas = []

    var map = createMap('mapid');
    var drawer = new Drawer();

    var requestSupportTruck = function (supportTruck_id) {
        supportTruck_id = supportTruck_id || ""; //si no se pasa un id, queda string vacio
        return $.ajax(url + urlTrucks + supportTruck_id);
    }
    var requestState = function (state_id) {
        return $.ajax(url + urlStates + state_id);
    }
    var responseExtract = function (attr, response) {
        return response[attr]
    }
    var extractSupportTruck = function (response) {
        return responseExtract('supportTruck', response);

    }
    var extractState = function (response) {

        return responseExtract('state', response);
    }
    var drawSupportTruck = function (supportTruck) {
        drawer.drawSupportTruckInMap(supportTruck, map);
    }

    var fillIdsArray = function (supportTrucks) {
        var supportTrucks = supportTrucks.supportTrucks;
        $.each(supportTrucks, function (i, elem) {
            trucksIds.push(elem.id);
        });
    }

    var resolveStateSupportTruck = function (supportTruck) {
        // pedimos el estado con el state_id, y retornamos el movil completo
        return requestState(supportTruck.state_id)
            .then(function (response) {
                supportTruck.state = response.state;
                delete supportTruck.state_id;
                return supportTruck;
            });
    }

    requestSupportTruck()       // pedimos los moviles al servidor
        .then(fillIdsArray)
        .done(function () {
            console.log("Ids cargados con exito: " + trucksIds);
        });


//HARDCODEADO
requestSupportTruck(606)            // pedimos un movil al servidor
        .then(extractSupportTruck)      // extraemos el movil de la respuesta del servidor 
        .then(resolveStateSupportTruck) // resolvemos el estado  
        .then(drawSupportTruck)         // dibujamos el movil con su estado 
        .done(function() {
            console.log("Fin.");
        });

//CON FOR EACH
trucksIds.forEach(function (supportTruck) {
            var promesa = requestSupportTruck(supportTruck)
            .then(extractSupportTruck)      // extraemos el movil de la respuesta del servidor 
            .then(resolveStateSupportTruck) // resolvemos el estado  
            .then(drawSupportTruck)         // dibujamos el movil con su estado 
            .done(function () {
                console.log("Fin.");
            });
        promesas.push(promesa)
    });
    Promise.all(promesas)
```

Comment: Qué quiere decir que "no te lo permite"? Se generá algún error? De dónde sale `trucksIds`? Poné un ejemplo de su contenido.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Estás teniendo un problema de a sincronía. Tu `array` de promesas tal como lo estás llenando sólo guarda promesas pendientes por resolver/rechazar. Además sin saber exactamente lo que realiza cada función que llamas dentro de tus procedimientos asíncronos(`requestSupportTruck`, `extractSupportTruck`, `resolveStateSupportTruck` y `drawSupportTruck`) será difícil saber cómo puedes resolver tu problema. Saludos

Comment: Agregué el cambio en base a lo que me solicitaron.